# How to hide a 'wrapper' just in the first section?

Tags: html, css

Here's a HTML first:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <!--=============== Hero content ===============-->
            <div class="content full-height hero-content" id="sec1">
```

The wrapper is a 20px padding (left,right):
Two white 20px padding on the screen's left and right. Moving all content(the whole page) closer.

[image]

I want this wrapper to disappear but only in the first section of the document.
How can i do it?

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do here? Please re-frame your question.

Comment: This wrapper has `id` so if you have more than one "wrapper" elements it a bad practice as `id` value should be unique per a page. Anyway, as far as I know, you can't change the properties of an elements by its children selectors.

Comment: Going further on the HTML:
Inside the <body> there's a <div id="wrapper"> what's use is only to make that white, 20px padding on the sides of the screen.
AND inside that <div id="wrapper"> there comes the rest... 
2 div:
1 for the main page
<div class="content full-height hero-content" id="sec1">
and 1 for the whole other content:
<div class="content">

The only thing i want to do is to make that wrapper padding 0px for the 'sec1' div. BUT only in phones. so putting that div outside of the wrapper is not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding a negative margin for `#sec1` in media query ?

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  #sec1{
   margin: -20px -20px 0;
  }
}
```